# Markers within Google Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got an issue, I can't make the marker clickable for my project. I've tried with google.com but nothing works. Can some one help me ?

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);

  <!--Add markers to map using previously specified locations-->
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  url:'http://www.google.com',
  title: 'Tobermory Distillery',
  map: map,
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind onclick to markers like this:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but where do I put the url ?